# how to parse a link in OOP PHP?

Tags: php

hi i have the following code in php:

```
    class parser {
    public function __construct($link)
    {
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file($link);
    if (!$xml) {
        echo 'Error while parsing the document';
        exit;
    }
    }
$file = urldecode($_REQUEST['ftitle']);
$obj = new parser($file);
```

i got the error that is mentioned in `if` part.

but if i try it in simple way mean to say i try for classless approach the whole piece of code work accurately with out any problem..plz tell me is there any error in my class-oriented approach.
thnx in advance :)

Comment: Remove `@` in front of `simplexml_load_file` to see what actual error is.

Comment: i have do this but in van :( and got the following error:
warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: Yes because the URL is not valid ... and not pointing to an XML file

Comment: the url is valid cause i have try to check it manually the needed file is downloaded.....also the format of that file is xml

Comment: i have done it plz check the following answer set by me

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not valid you are missing `}` at the end .... and using `@` to suppress error is not adviced

`!$xml` would be true so use this instead

```
 if ($xml === false) {
```

What do i mean  ???

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<body />");

var_dump(!$xml); // returns true
var_dump($xml);  // return object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
```

Comment: I think missing brace is just a typo.

Comment: @PLB added additional information ...

Comment: i have done it plz check the following answer set by me

Comment: What do you mean by its not working well ?? tested it myself

Answer (score 0):

try this i think this would help you because its working accurately at my localhost

```
class parser {
    public function __construct($link)
    {
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file($link); // replace it with the following line.
    $xml =new SimpleXMLElement($link, NULL, TRUE);
    if (!$xml) {
        echo 'Error while parsing the document';
        exit;
    } //if end
    } //constructor end
    } //class end
$file = urldecode($_REQUEST['ftitle']); //replace it with the following line.
$file = $_REQUEST['ftitle'];
$obj = new parser($file);
```